# Merging Models into one with copying data using Entity Framework 6.1

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have 3 models which almost holds the similar data. Now I want to create a new model with properties from the 3 models. I did that. But the problem I am facing is, I am losing the data in 3 tables when I apply migration.

I want to copy data from 3 tables into the new table when I apply migrations to the database. Seed method runs after applying the migrations, by the time all 3 tables are dropped. I want to have some method which runs before applying migrations and stores the data in some temp table and pushes this temp table data to new table and deletes temp table.

Is there any way we can achieve that with Entity Framework or do I need to handle this explicitly?

My model classes are  :

```
public class Model1 { 
   public Guid Id {get;set;}

   public int Count {get;set;}

   public bool IsActive {get;set;}

   public string Template {get;set;}
}

public class Model2 { 
   public Guid Id {get;set;}

   public int Count {get;set;}

   public string Template {get;set;}
}

public class Model3 { 
   public Guid Id {get;set;}

   public int Count {get;set;}

   public string Template {get;set;}
}

public class NewModel{ 
   public Guid Id {get;set;}

   public int Count {get;set;}

   public string Template {get;set;}

   public bool IsActive {get;set;}

   public string Type {get;set; }    // this will the type of all 3 old models
}
```

Comment: Migrations don't drop tables when properly configured. You need to setup a baseline migration with your original 3 tables (add-migration Initial -IgnoreChanges), apply that migration (update-database), then add your table and a new migration. Then you can just use the migration seed to move the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it manually, editing the generated migration using the Sql("select into ecc")